# How to change the size of the browser window when running the FirefoxWebDriverProvider in JBehave Web

Tags: selenium, jbehave

We're using JBehave Web to drive our selenium test suite for a new project and really like the Etsy.com example available on JBehave, especially the Java/Spring maven archetype as this fits in with our architecture.

The biggest problem so far has been documentation, which is why I'm posting here in the hopes that I can get some help from others in a similar situation.

It looks like JBehave Web only provides a "FirefoxWebDriverProvider" class and no corresponding one for Chrome. Has anyone else run into this problem? Have you written your own ChromeDriverProvider?

Also, we need to change the size of the browser that comes up by default and I can't seem to find a way of doing that during the bootstrapping of the test run.

We're using the Maven archetype: jbehave-web-selenium-java-spring-archetype which uses the jbehave-maven-plugin and the "run-stories-with-annotated-embedder" goal so we're using the "Annotated" method of extending the InjectableEmbedder.

If anyone can provide some guidance, I'd really appreciate it, even if just pointers to more examples.

Comment: JBehave does provide Chrome but you have to load the Chrome binary somehow (or use SauceLabs).  I'm still trying to figure out how it works.  Hey, I started a local grid on 4444 and I am running JBehave-Web Jetty server but when I load a story from that spring Etsy example, it doesn't run.  How did you do it?

Answer (score 12):

### How To Resize Window

```
webDriverProvider.get().manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

You can easily find code like this by navigating through the code. If you are using Eclipse, *Open Declaration* and *Quick Type Hierarchy* options are everything you need.

### How to Use Chrome Driver

You can use `TypeWebDriverProvider` or `PropertyWebDriverProvider`. For instance:

```
new TypeWebDriverProvider(ChromeDriver.class);
```

Comment: We ended up finding this Chrome Driver and it's been working great: http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/GettingStarted.

It can take a parameter when it is bootstrapped to start in maximized mode and also exposes the capability to add extensions when it starts up.

Comment: @GinoFilicetti Chrome Driver downloads have been moved to http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: The Code "Window resizing" works perfect for me. I do not understand why or when the part in "ChromeWebDriverProvideer" is needed.

Comment: @leo The question also mentions the use of Chrome instead of Firefox. I’ll update the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 621));
```

Answer (score 2):

What jokka said is correct, justr a side note: Before resizing window, I always put it to top left corner, so I know that WebDriver can "see" everything:

```
driver.get().manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
```

Obviously, the `driver` above is assumed healthy instance of WebDriverProvider

Answer (score 2):

We ended up finding this [Chrome Driver](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/GettingStarted) and it's been working great. It can take a parameter when it is bootstrapped to start in maximized mode and also exposes the capability to add extensions when it starts up.

Comment: That's the Chrome driver that everyone uses.  http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(x, y);
```

This works fine for me. The x and y are in a feature file.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

This is working fine for me.

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1800, 1000)
```