# Can I and how to use headless chrome to get the full size of a webpage?

Tags: headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I did read the docs here:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

and here:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/examples

and couldn't find a way.

I'm trying to get the highlighted value, illustrated below, that I would get with developer tools -> network when loading a webpage.

[image: I'm trying to get this value]

Comment: not really an answer, but may get you in the right direction:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806998/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-browser-window-when-running-the-firefoxwebdriverpr
you might have to find the equivalent for this (OR make the question more precise :) )